# Installing requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, postgresql, wagtail

I am new to the Wagtail cms and am taking over a friend's project for his site.

I have downloaded his repo and am trying to get it to run locally. I have followed the steps on the wagtail documentation http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12.1/getting_started/index.html

but in the site's requirements.txt file, there are some dependencies that just are not installing and giving errors:

here is the output of when trying to install the requirements:

```
build\lib.win32-2.7\psycopg2\_psycopg.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 62 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Users\\Adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

 Rolling back uninstall of psycopg2
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\Adam\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-
bykm5e\\psycopg2\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\Adam\appdata\local\temp\pip-
cidizd-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --
compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\Adam\appdata\local\temp\pip-
build-bykm5e\psycopg2\
```

(The full output is here: https://pastebin.com/m1ukkei8)

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I am using Python 2.7 and have tried reinstalling  psycopg and have installed postresql

Comment: Which SO are you using?

Comment: Sorry, what is SO? @lapinkoira

Comment: sorry, I mean, operating system, OS* which windows' version

Comment: Oh, haha - windows 10 @lapinkoira

Comment: Try http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

Comment: @lapinkoira note that this is outdated psycopg2 version you are proposing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your windows linker is throwing out errors as you don't have c++ libraries for an extension to be built properly.

I would suggest to you to rather install it  through wheel  [file](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2)

by running

```
pip install some-package.whl
```

Comment: Okay, so I installed it again via wheel file - all okay and now it has gotten further in the installation but running into other errors now! https://pastebin.com/m4hG7zHZ  but apart from them it has helped so thanks!

Comment: Your have error with next package pylibmc. 
I am not confident if pylibmc has windows port yet

Comment: ah sh** .... okay haha will have to get it running on Heroku or something instead! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the answer, but the version of psycopg2 that you're using had [a bug](https://psycopg.lighthouseapp.com/projects/62710/tickets/18) that prevented installation using pip, due to [some bug in pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1630). Try version 2.5.3 and see if that fixes it.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with the what he is facing on windows :)